# Is there a function similar to stoi that would work for a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I've created a class for complex numbers for an assignment last week and our next assignment is to modify this class to be a template class. Part of the assignment was overloading the extraction operator, and originally when only dealing with int, I took the whole input line as a string and made substrings for the real and imaginary parts, then I used stoi to convert the parts to ints which I could store (This is what my professor suggested doing). However, now that this is is a template class stoi no longer works if the type being used is double, float, etc. Is there a function that works similarly but across different types? Or possibly another solution altogether that may work better?

I tried using if statements to detect what type is being used and then using stoi, stod, etc. accordingly however, this seems less than ideal because it only works for the types I explicitly define, and I'm sure this isn't what they're looking for.

```
template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& in,MyComplex<T> &num){
  string inString;
  getline(in, inString);
  T test = 3.33;
   if(test != 3.33){
    //convert using stoi
  }
   else if(test == 3.33){
    //convert using stod
  }
 //etc.
}
```

I left out what's inside the brackets because it's very long and doesn't change the fact that I can only define for a finite amount of data types. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you need `stoi` in the first place? `in >> num.real >> num.imag;`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, the input that needs to be accepted is in the form "4 + 5i" for example, not just "4 5"

Comment: Note the existence of [`std::complex<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) { ... } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) { ... } else ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the input stream directly. It seems like your input format is `2.3 + 5i`, so you can use the following code:

```cpp
double a,b;
char c; 
in >> a >> c >> b; // c eats the +; let's the i in the in
in >> c; // eats the i
```

Note that then we also can use `c` two times in the same line, I just wanted space for my comments so I put it on the next.

A more general note to your code:
The "right" way to check what type `T` is (or maybe just what attributes the type has, since you probably don't need to differentiate between say `int` and `long`), is to use [type traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).

But, for having completely different implementations for different types, you should use different implementations, so declare a method that takes `MyComplex<double>`, one that takes `MyComplex<int>`, etc.